# Why does Mathematica WolframScript get file fail?

Tags: cdfplayer, scripting

I use Mathematica 11 and create a project containing two files: a package file named `MyPackage.m` and the other named `run.m`. The package file contains just normal functions not in special Mathematica package structure ([see here](https://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/applications/packages.html)), and the other contains code to get `MyPackage.m` and use the functions.

```
(* Package.m *)
myFun[x_String] := Print[x]
...

(* run.m *)
<<"Package.m"
myFun["Hello,World"]
```

I put these two files into one directory and ensure that the `$path` contains the directory path. But, when I run `wolframscript -file ./run.m -print all`, it complains `$Failed`. The question is: how to import another file when using `wolframscript`? It seems cannot find the destination file even they are in the same directory.

I use Mathematica 11 and run `wolframscript` in Ubuntu server where I have installed the latest Free CDF Player.

---

After installing the whole Mathematica at my Ubuntu server, `wolframscript` run as expected. Maybe the `free CDF Player` cannot give the full function.

Comment: What happens if you replace the contents of `run.m` with something like `Print[Directory[]]; Print[ FindFile[ "Package.m" ] ];Exit[]`?

Comment: Does your *.wl* or *.wls* file have the Unix required "shebang" line at the top as specified in the [Wolfram Language Scripts](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WolframLanguageScripts.html) tutorial?  Did you start with *File | New | Package (.wl)* or *File | New | Script(.wls)*?  These add a "shebang" line for Unix to the file.  Details can also be found in the help on how to construct a more specific "shebang" line. See [WolframScript](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html) help.

Comment: Also, I am not certain that `wolframscript` will run using the Free CDF Player.  For one thing the free CDF player cannot load packages so I doubt that even if you could run a *.wl* or *.wls* file on it that you would be able to load packages. I think you would need to use the *-local* or *-cloud* command line options to point `wolframscript` to a fully licensed kernel.

Comment: @JasonB. Print[Directory[]] and Print[FindFile["Package.m"]] show correctly. It can find the file "Package.m".

Comment: @Edmund I'm new to Mathematica and do not know exactly the difference between `.wl` and `.m`. I follow the tutorial on the web using Mathematica Eclipse plugin to create project which contains just `.m` file and a notebook file. And the `wolframscript` is installed at the same time when I install CDF player in Linux.

Comment: @Edmund I can run only the `Package.m` by using `wolframscript`, it failed when using `Get or (<<)` to import another package or file.

Comment: @hliu what do you mean you can only run it with wolframscript? Can you not do it in a standard Mathematica session?

Comment: @b3m2a1Sorry for my poor English..The Mathematica is not installed in my  Ubuntu server, only the free CDF Player installed. I found wolframscript was installed at the same time after installing CDF Player, so I decide to use wolframscript to run the script.

Comment: `ToExpression@ReadString@"Package.m" ` works with wolframscript+CDF

Answer (score 3):

Only the full version of Mathematica can evaluate arbitrary code. You have the free CDF player.  The CDF player can only open CDF files previously prepared and digitally signed with a full version of Mathematica. It does not allow writing and running new (i.e. unsigned) code.